# I need to combine about 800 UV map projections into just one

Tags: texturing, uv

I've searched for similar questions and haven't found any that apply, but maybe I'm searching for the wrong terms.

Here's my problem:

I created an OBJ in iClone that combines hundreds of smaller parts, & I have joined them in Blender. None of them had a UV texture, just a mesh color. I have also successfully removed all internal faces, doubled verts, etc.

The problem now is that whenever I try to apply a texture to my joined object, it applies it only to a tiny section of the object, rather than the entire object. How do I unify all UV projections so that they render one continuous texture all over, rather than having it repeat constantly? I also don't want to lose my verts, I'll need them for sculpting.

I apologize if this is a simple thing, but it has been perplexing me!

Thank you for any help!

Thank you!

[EDIT] Here is the object I'm working on, it's the back of a pair of leather suspenders:

[image]

As you can see, it's only applying the texture I've selected (the 'bricks' one just as an example) to one small segment of the belt, instead of the entire piece, even though all of those segments have been merged into one piece.

The materials are still in hundreds of pieces, needlessly.

What I want to do is the SAME thing I did when I merged the parts into one, but I want to do it with the MATERIALS, instead. That way I would just be skinning one thing, rather than hundreds of things.

I don't yet have a UV map, but I think what I need to do involves making one...

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Could you please add an image of your model and your UV map?

Comment: Thank you very much! I edited my original post, so perhaps it can be more informative!

Comment: How many material slots are there on the selected object?

Comment: I selected "remove all material slots" for each belt on the whole object. I then assigned a built-in texture image (the bricks again), and it worked!

I then tried to import the object into iclone, and the texture was still repeated for every face. So then I went back to blender, added the leather texture image I wanted to use, and sure enough, it wasn't working.

So I went into the material properties tab, changed a few settings (most notably "texture coordinate" under "vector"), and suddenly it works great with a manually added texture, as well! 

I was sure the problem was fixed.

Comment: ...But it wasn't, and now I am officially out of ideas, because it looks PERFECT in blender - just exactly the way I want it to, but it still does not render correctly in iclone. It still assigns the texture to just one face, it now just uses only one material, and renders all of them at once on the item, rather than skinning the whole thing with one continuous image, as it does in blender.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I think what I need is to STOP syncing faces with materials? I saw somewhere that that was possible to do, but now I can't find it... If I did that, then perhaps it could stop rendering the entire texture onto each face?

Comment: I think I just figured out why this is happening. Apparently blender isn't exporting my material settings. I confirmed this by loading up exported *.OBJ files. Some settings like the color of the anodized material, and the "vector > texture coordinate" settings, are not saved upon *.OBJ export. I have to change those back each time I load them. That is likely why they are not displaying correctly in my engine. Is this a plugin issue? I'm running v2.2 of the materials plugin, is there a newer one, or some other reason why this could be happening, other than a bug?